# sorting a list of class instances by date in python

Tags: python, list, class, sorting, oop

I have a list containing instances of a class, which i want to sort by date but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. It needs to be in ascending order. The function im working on has to add the new instance of a class but in chronological order in the list.

Ive tried using a for loop through the list and insert the new instance before the one that its greater than but that just causes doubles of my smallest instance.
Ive also tried using the .sort method which i am unsure how to implement with this.

attributes of class = name, id, datetime('some date'),content

```
 def add_new(self, new: class_name ) -> None:
    """Add new instance to class_list the  for this class, if new_instance was posted at a
    later date. Otherwise, do not add to class_list.

    new_instances must be added in chronological order.
    """

    if reply.date >= self.date:
        self._class_list.append(reply)
    self._class_list.sort(key = lambda x: )
```

i am unsure what to add for x? As all the dates in the class instances are in the form datetime('random date')

Comment: Why lambda?? Simply using list.sort() doesn't work?

Comment: no it doesnt! because the date is an one of 4 instance attributes of the class objects in the list

Comment: self._class_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])

Answer (score 1):

You can access the class attribute holding the date and then sort. Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = datetime.now()

some_instances = []
for i in range(3):
    a = A()
    some_instances.append(a)

some_instances = sorted(some_instances, key=lambda x: x.date)

for instance in some_instances:
    print(instance, instance.date)
```

Which prints:

```
# <__main__.A object at 0x7fda760e62b0> 2019-09-19 19:02:06.887805
# <__main__.A object at 0x7fda76031be0> 2019-09-19 19:02:06.887810
# <__main__.A object at 0x7fda7603f908> 2019-09-19 19:02:06.887811
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort) goes, the way to handle this is with their `key` argument. You would want to do something like the following:

```py
def key(x):
    return x.date
```

Or if you really want to be using lambdas:

```py
lambda x: x.date
```

Do note, though, that this will only sort by date. If you want to sort by *all* properties, then you have two options.

1. You can have the key function return a tuple of attributes to sort by, or
2. You can define comparison methods on your class.

The documentation for the comparison methods can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__ge__#object.__lt__). They let you do actual comparisons between instances of your class, which means you wouldn't need to pass anything to list.sort() at all.